# How to match more than 2 side by side

Tags: python, list, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently using python and having trouble finding a code. I have 2 data frames that I would like to match more than 2 numbers that match side by side. For example, I would like to lookup the numbers in df1 and find more than 2 numbers match side by side in df2.

```
import pandas as pd 
cols = ['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6,8,9,10]], columns=cols)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6,8],
           [2,5,6,20,22,23,34],
           [3,8,12,13,34,45,46],
           [4,9,10,14,29,32,33],
           [5,1,22,13,23,33,35],
           [6,1,6,7,8,9,10],
           [7,0,2,3,5,6,8]], 
           columns = ['Id','Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

I would like my results to be something like this.

```
results = pd.DataFrame([[6,1,6,7,8,9,10]],             
       columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

You can see Id 6 or index 6 has 8,9,10. More than 2 number match side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Hope that help you .

```
    # step1: extract values to compare from df1 and df2
list1=df2[['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6']].values.tolist() 
list2=df1[['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6']].values.tolist()
#step 2: out the ligne that value in list1 equal value list2 and the same Number in tow data frame 
k=[]
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        if df1.columns[i]==df2.columns[i+1] and list1[j][i]==list2[0][i]:
            k.append(j)
#step3 count how many time values match more than 2 numbers that match side by side
count = {}
for i in k:
    count[i] = k.count(i)
#step4: return result thats in condition match more than 2 numbers that match side by side


out=[] 
for i in count:
    if count[i]>2:
       out.append(i)

result= df2.loc[out].reset_index()
```

result:

```
index  Id  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
0      5   6     1     6     7     8     9    10
```

Comment: Got a message saying. The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  out_result=out_result.append(df2.loc[i],ignore_index=True)

Comment: i fixe it for you . i remplace df.append with  list.append() enjoy! mark it like a Answer and Upvote it

Comment: it works but does not work with a long dataframe.

Comment: Its giving me this error if its a long dataframe(df2). index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6.

Comment: Hi @Chris try now i remplace 6 by lenth of list1 (row in df2)

Comment: error saying index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6

Comment: i resolved it. i replace it with len(list1)-1